# the kenpo tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently I made a contribution to the site. I added some information about the kenpo tag wiki.

I noticed that both of my contributions where rejected by a certain user with the following reason

> This edit plagiarizes content from an external source without proper attribution.

I dont understand this.

I have tried to attribute all sources.

Please explain what I did wrong.

This is the contribution for the excerpt

https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/761

This is the tag wiki

https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/760

Do I need to give attribution as part of the excerpt in addition to the tag wiki? even then, I did give attribution in the tag wiki, but that was rejected on the grounds of plagiarism, I don't understand. Could someone explain the correct way that I should conduct myself in this regard.

Comment: Sorry, hombre. I thought the policy was against wholesale porting from wikipedia. I was wrong.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann i am offended by your comment. i did not wholesave port from wikipedia. you are misrepresenting me. i do not wish to enter into any arguments. kindly retract your heinous accusations.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way. I literally meant that I thought the policy was against direct copying from Wikipedia. That's how we do it at Fitness.SE. Because that's okay here on MA.SE, your edit was accepted and I apologized.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be too concerned yet - at this very moment your suggestions are still in the review queue. As a community driven site it takes several people to agree before your suggestion is accepted or rejected. Typically ♦ moderators will stay out of that process and let the rest of the community take care of it.

The person who voted to reject your suggestion might post their exact reason here in response to your question, but they are not obligated to.

As for attribution, it is good to have the source of excerpted material clearly marked. You can do this by using direct quotes, and use appropriate markdown so it

> appears in a quote box like this.

Additionally you can use superscript numbers to refer to a reference or attribution list at the bottom of your suggestion, much like Wikipedia does. You had a list of links at the bottom, so maybe you just need to organise that list a little better so it's obvious which were used as sources for your suggestion and which are simply helpful/interesting third party sites.

**Edit:** your suggestion has been accepted.